# OpenGL state reset

Tags: java, opengl, graphics, processing

I'm having some issues regarding AWT and processing (which they don't recommend), I cant get a clear start most of the time and processing draw loop stops working, the issues are various but they seems mainly linked to graphics matrix depth.

Seeing how this problem seems related on starting conditions (if it starts it doesn't fail later or else it doesn't start). I was wondering if there was some way to totally floor the graphics state, even at the cost of running the application full-screen.

So the question is mainly, how can I (if possible) pro grammatically obtain a fresh start on graphics? Of course any other solution or input is welcome and it could be of some use for processing itself.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to reset a OpenGL context do the default state. And even if there were, this wouldn't solve your problem, because your troubles seem to arise from the fact that when your code is done it doesn't leave behind the OpenGL context in the state it found it when entering. That certainly is not the default state.

However what's possible is, that you create OpenGL context just for your code and temporarily switch to that, to do your thing and then back to the original one. Windows are not tied to OpenGL contexts, and OpenGL contexts are not tied to windows; it's pick and mix as you desire (as long as pixel formats are compatible, which they are for the majority of window/context setups).

If you want/need access to OpenGL objects (textures, buffer objects) created by Processing you can share context data (which does not share state, so you're safe). Just don't modify or outright delete stuff that your code doesn't own.

The one problem you're going to run into is doing all of that using JOGL/AWT. At a quick glance at the library reference I found no obvious way to figure out which *drawable* the currently active OpenGL context is bound to; it's easy enough to get the current context though. However JOGL itself is open source, so if there's no readily available way to do this, it should be easy enough to implement (also a worthwhile addition to the library, then).

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard OpenGL function to do that, but you can create your own function to reset all bindings, options and capabilities to the defaults defined in the OpenGL standard. But as *@datenwolf* said in his answer, maybe switching between contexts fits better to your problem. Choose the solution which fits best to your use case.